# Video Clip is Being Rotated in Movie Clip Editor

Tags: tracking, movie-clip-editor

I've seen a question similar to this one, but it didn't answer my problem.
I have a video that I took on my phone that I'm trying to open in the Video Clip Editor, but whenever I open it, it is rotated sideways.  However, the video shouldn't be sideways, because when I play the video in a player like VLC, it is oriented correctly.
It seems like Blender is changing the orientation of the image when its opened.  I'm not sure why though.  Is it because of Resolution settings?  I've got the resolution X and Y values set to the dimensions of the phone picture size, so that shouldn't be the issue.
Is there an easy way to rotate the video IN the movie clip editor?
Thanks

**EDIT**

After @moonboots' suggestion, I tried using the Video Sequence Editor to flip the video, following this video that @moonboots posted: [youtube.com/watch?v=hfo-DRGvkgo](http://%20youtube.com/watch?v=hfo-DRGvkgo)

The result worked when I rendered the animation and loaded it into the Movie Editor.  However, I had this issue where I had a sliver of video at the bottom which was just alpha.  What did I do wrong?
Here's an image of my settings.  My video width x height is 480 x 800

[image: properties]

Thanks!

Comment: does this video answer? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hfo-DRGvkgo

Comment: @moonboots, thanks for your reply!  Please see my edit.